# cshtml view if inside of foreach inside of else

Tags: c#, sql, razor

I'm trying to display records in my view. I only want to display records that don't have a null value for the TABLE_NUMBER1 field. I've set this up, but am having a weird issue where it won't recognize the closing tag for the else, only the foreach and if. Specifically, if I add a closing tag for the else, it recognizes it as the closing tag for the entire razer section (aka it's gold).

```
@if (Model.Count() == 0)
{
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">
            No Records match search criteria
        </td>
    </tr>
        </tbody>  
}  
else{          
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    var hiderows = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TABLE_NUMBER1).ToString();
    if (hiderows != null)
    {     
        <tbody>       
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p class="one">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PNTR_MAX)</p>
        </td>
            <td>
            <p class="one">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EFFECTIVE_DATE1)</p>
        </td>
            <td>
            <p class="one">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BANK_ROUTING_NUMBER)</p>
        </td>
            <td>
            <p class="one">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TAX_ID)</p>
        </td>
            <td>
            <p class="one">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BANK_NAME)</p>
        </td>
            <td>
            <p class="one">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.COMPANY_NAME1)</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "..\\Table9\\Edit", new { id = item.EFTID }) 
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "..\\Table9\\Details", new { id = item.EFTID }) 
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "..\\Table9\\Delete", new { id = item.EFTID })
        </td>               
    </tr>
</tbody>
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
var hiderows = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TABLE_NUMBER1);
```

change it to :

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TABLE_NUMBER1)
 if (item.TABLE_NUMBER1!= null)
{
```